# Maven: Could Not find Artifact when trying to include a project in another one using dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

### Problem description

I have a project called `reservationVol` which I want to include in an mvc spring project called `reservationVolMvc`. I compiled and tested `reservationVol` on eclipse. I also use the maven commands: `mvn compile` and `mvn package`. All tests ran successfully.

When I tried to compile `reservationVolMvc` using the `mvn compile` command I get the following error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building reservationVolSpring 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for hani.reservationVol:reservationVol:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.688 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-23T12:25:21+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/77M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project reservationVolSpring: Could not resolve dependencies for project formation.addstones:reservationVolSpring:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact hani.reservationVol:reservationVol:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

The following **pom.xml**  files represent the dependencies for respectively `reservationVol` and `reservationVolMvc`. I included the project `ReservationVol` in `reservationVolMvc` by using the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>hani.reservationVol</groupId>
    <artifactId>reservationVol</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

---

## ReservationVol

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>hani.reservationVol</groupId>
        <artifactId>reservationVol</artifactId>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>reservationVol</name>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.39</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            
             <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.12</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
           
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.3</version>
              <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>
        </build>
        
    </project>
```

---

## reservationVolMvc

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>formation.addstones</groupId>
    <artifactId>reservationVolSpring</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>reservationVolSpring</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>hani.reservationVol</groupId>
                <artifactId>reservationVol</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Do a `mvn clean install`. 
This will clean whatever created from the previous build, then build your project and add the jars to your local maven repository (.m2\repository)

Answer (score 12):

I also faced the same problem...................Issue got resolved
Do a maven clean and install of the child project and then try

maven clean  and install of parent project.

For reference watch these  videos
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2aNC1EAnpqo
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMfd2FwKKHY

Comment: Watching the vids helped....

Answer (score 7):

I was facing the same issue, I had a parent project that would fail on the Clean Install of a dependent project.

I tried all of the above solutions to no avail, running clean install both in eclipse and from command line.

I was able to solve by navigating to the Child Project and Running the following

1. Cleaning the project `mvn clean`
2. Setting as eclipse project `mvn eclipse:eclipse` (this forced download of missing jars)
3. Follow by clean install of Child project `mvn clean install -U`
4. Finally clean install on parent project `mvn clean install -DskipTests -P(if necessary a profile here) -U`

This helped when maven was not downloading jar's properly listed in the pom.xml, I was not able to find why clean install with Update Snapshots/etc. did not download the missing jars.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, I ran:

```
    mvn compile dependency:tree
```

and after that it compiled without any problem.